# Terraform Cloud in Git mode - failed to read schema, permission denied

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm new to terraform and trying to use a 'custom' provider with Terraform cloud. To be clear, if I use it on my Windows machine without the TCloud everything works just fine.
On the TCloud I've got a workbook synchronized to my Git repo. The custom provider is uploaded to the Git repo: \terraform.d\plugins\zscaler.com\zpa\zpa\2.0.5\linux_amd64\terraform-provider-zpa_v2.0.5.

I've ran the chmod command to compensate for Window's lack of ability to set the provider as executable:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x .\terraform.d\plugins\zscaler.com\zpa\zpa\2.0.5\linux_amd64\terraform-provider-zpa_v2.0.5
```

I've also updated the lock file to allow both windows and linux provider hashes to deal with "local provider doesn't match any of the checksums" issue:

```
terraform providers lock -fs-mirror="C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\terraform.d\plugins\"  -platform=windows_amd64 -platform=linux_amd64 zscaler.com/zpa/zpa
```

When I run terraform plan from VSCode (on my Windows machine) on the repo that's initialized to the TCloud I get the following error:

```
> terraform plan -var-file terraform.tfvar
 . . .
2022-02-02T10:14:28.328-0600 [INFO]  cloud: starting Plan operation

Terraform v1.1.4
on linux_amd64
Configuring remote state backend...
Initializing Terraform configuration...
╷
│ Error: failed to read schema for zpa_provisioning_key.iot_edge_key in zscaler.com/zpa/zpa: failed to instantiate provider "zscaler.com/zpa/zpa" to obtain schema: fork/exec .terraform/providers/zscaler.com/zpa/zpa/2.0.5/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-zpa_v2.0.5: permission denied
```

Enabling debug doesn't give me any more clue on what's wrong. Appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried adding the provider to your registry on TFCloud and installing it from in the normal way?

Comment: So far I could only upload a module to TFCloud and not sure how to call it in the "provider" section. Don't see a way to upload a provider

```
module "zpa" {
      source  = "app.terraform.io/Test/zpa/provider"
      version = "2.0.5"
    }
```

Comment: Ok that may not yet be in TFCloud, and it exists in TFE only as bundles for isolated networks still I believe.

Comment: Git doesn't have this level of access control on files (the only thing it has is that chmod +x or -x flag), so this has nothing to do with Git itself. It's some sort of OS or Terraform setup item.